# VisualStudio CMake dynamic library: include/link all used functions in *single* dll

Tags: c++, visual-studio, dll, cmake, visual-studio-2019

I have a VisualStudio-2019 C++ Project which uses CMake and Ninja to build a dll, the Project uses functions from a few Libraries like `protobuf` and `spdlog`, which I have installed using `vcpkg`.

When building, the output gets written to four distinct dll files and all of them are needed for the `main-dll` to run.
Below are two screenshots: left the current state and right the expected state.

[image: too many dependencies] [image: expectd result]

The `main.dll` file should include all the functions it imports, the compiler shouldn't create separate dlls for each library.

I don't which know knob I need to turn, I can imagine several ways to edit:

- The C++ Code of the Project (Classes, inlining functions ?)
- The CMakeList.txt
- The Arguments of MSVC (compiler, linker flags)
- The Arguments of Ninja

Where should I start ?

Comment: In CMake, the default library is shared(dll). So, it produces dll for each target. You need to  find add_library for spdlog, fmt and protobuf and make it static explicitly. Or, provide a minimal code and I can tell you where to change.

Comment: @asitdhal - no, in CMake the default is _static_. You have to manually set `BUILD_SHARED_LIBS` to `YES` (or another true-y value) to change that default.

Comment: @AlexReinking Here in the cmake documentation, https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/variable/BUILD_SHARED_LIBS.html BUILD_SHARED_LIBS is ON by default. Users have to make if OFF to make static as the default build. The static or dynamic is not a cmake thing, it comes from the underlying OS. In both Linux and Windows, the default library build is static. CMake tries hard not to be suprising.

Comment: @asitdhal you're not quoting from the documentation. I don't know what you're reading, but that page says very explicitly that BUILD_SHARED_LIBS must be defined and true. By default, it is not defined at all, so false. Try it yourself

Comment: @asitdhal - "If no type is given explicitly the type is STATIC or SHARED based on whether the current value of the variable BUILD_SHARED_LIBS is ON." https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/add_library.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Setting the mentioned flags or appending `-static` to the import library components had no effect, I went as far as

```
set(BUILD_SHARED_LIBS OFF)
set(CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS "-static")
set(CMAKE_MODULE_LINKER_FLAGS "-static")
set(CMAKE_SHARED_LINKER_FLAGS "-static")
set(CMAKE_STATIC_LINKER_FLAGS "-static")
```

But this didn't help a bit.

As it turned out this is a problem with `vcpkg`:
I had installed the packages with the triplet `x64-windows`, which builds for dynamic linkage, installing the packages with
`vcpkg install --triplet=x64-windows-static protobuf spdlog` makes static linking possible. If the static variants are not installed, the build proceeds silently with the dynamic ones.